# Regular expression to match any number NOT ending in zero

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm asking for input for a dice game.
It really matters whether or not the number entered is divisible by ten.

I have \d+0 for the numbers that DO end in zero.

I need one for the number that DO NOT end in zero.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\d+[1-9]
```

Should work, I think.

This will match at least one digit followed by a non-zero digit.

However, you very likely need to embed this in some way, either by anchoring it:

```
^\d+[1-9]$
```

to verify that the complete string only contains that number (but then you can also convert said string to a number and do a mod 10).

The way you have it currently (and also the expression in your question) it would match a number like `1203` without problems for both expressions, since regexes match *substrings* unless you anchor them (except in some environments where they are anchored by default like that – I think Java does that).

Also this works for at least two digits only, as does the expression you posted in your question. I assume that to be intentional. If not, then the `+` should probably be a `*` in both cases.

Comment: This does not match single digit numbers, I fear.

Comment: @Joey this way don't match with 1 digit number (ie 5).

Comment: If you're going to do something like this... might as well just make the regex: [1-9]+

Comment: Hyperboreus, Zote: Neither does the expression he posted in his question.

Comment: kchau: Nope, that would prevent numbers like `103`.

Answer (score 15):

Maybe this would do the trick

```
\d*[1-9]
```

Comment: Ah, damn. I fiddled about 15 seconds with the minimum post length, I think :-)

Comment: This answer appeals to me more because of how vague the original question is in terms of environment; it specifically mentions regex.  Also, this sounds like a simple regex homework problem.

Answer (score 12):

This is not a good use of regular expressions.

I suggest the [modulus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) or integer division operators.

```
if (number % 10) {
  // number doesn't end in zero
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
\d*[1-9]
```

Works better.

Answer (score 2):

I think (d%10==0) is a better way to test divisibility by 10.

Answer (score 1):

Divisibility trick is valid for integers not for decimals.

What if someone tris to verify this:

```
123.120
```

It ends with a non significant zero.

So 123.12/X and 123.120/X gives same result
Same for 123.12%X and 123.120%X
(This last is not valid operation since value is not an integer, so can not get module of a float/number)

Module can only be getted for integer values (integer/integer).

And also someone can be trying to look for:

```
AnyTextWithNumbersNotEndingOnZero_0  <--- Not valid
AnyTextWithNumbersNotEndingOnZero    <--- Valid
```

So the best an more clear can be somethng like this:

```
/[0-9]*0$/
```

Hope helps.

Ah! and if want letters and numbers but last not be a zero:

```
/[0-9A-Za-z]*0$/
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

If you want use regular expression , try this regular expression

```
  ^([1-9]+)$
```

Using Plain JavaScript
     var num =temp;

```
if(temp % 10 !==0){

//your code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one to exclude 0

```
\d+[^0]?
```

Comment: this way don't match with 1 digit number (ie 5).

Comment: Your expression matches 12, 120, 1000, 12C and 100D for instance.